# Why does $\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}(\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^\mu}}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda})=\frac{d^2x^\nu}{d\lambda^2}$?

Tags: chain-rule, general-relativity

Why does $\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}(\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^\mu}}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda})=\frac{d^2x^\nu}{d\lambda^2}$?

I have got as far as using the product rule:

($\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^\mu}})\frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda}+\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^\mu}}(\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda})$

but don't know how to evaluate the mixing of partial and total derivatives.

Comment: There's something wrong with the indices.  The free index on the LHS is $\mu$ but the free index on the RHS is $\nu$.